# Lebesgue integral question (double integral)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $g,h$ be nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that

### $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)^2h(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\int_{\{t\in\mathbb{R}:g(t)>x\}}2h(t)x\,dtdx.$$

I am lost on how to approach this question.

Change of variable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the integrands are non-negative, [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) tells us order of integration is interchangable.
$$\mathrm{
\int_0^\infty\int_{\{t:g(t)>x\}}2h(t)x\,dt\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\{x:\,0<x<g(t)\}}2h(t)x\,dx\,dt\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int^{g(t)}_{0}2h(t)x\,dx\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)^2h(t)\,dt
}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given, but in case you don't see how to interchange the order clearly:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{\{t\in \mathbb{R}:g(t)>x\}}2h(t)x\,dt\,dx &= \int_{\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0\leq x<g(t)\}} 2h(t)x\,dt\,dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}h(t)\int_0^{g(t)}2x\,dx\,dt \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}g^2h\,dm.
\end{align}